# I can't add a specific friend in league of legends

Tags: league-of-legends

We are in the same server EUWest and i can see his profile, i can add anyone else just fine but when i try to add him it says "yikes, internal server error, please try again later". I've tried several times in different days and when he tries to add me the friend request never arrives, any help?

Answer (score 2):

It seems to be a program problem, try to contact Riot technical support adding a screenshot with the returned message.

Answer (score 1):

This seems to be an ongoing problem, and there has been a notice sitting in the game client for quite a while:

[image: Client Notification "Friends List Issues"]

Even though you posted this before they acknowledged the issue, if you (or someone else) are still experiencing the issue, you can try Riot's suggestions.  The link in the screenshot just leads you to a Twitter post of those suggestions:

https://twitter.com/RiotSupport/status/1218333629606055936

Answer (score 1):

You or him need to remove some of the friend requests you all sent out...

You can only send a certain amount of request... so you won't be able to add anyone unless some of your request are accepted or removed.